# How to use an unknown (int-like) type as index into std::vector?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, vector, typedef

I'm using a type `Id` which is defined in another part of the code I'm using:

```
typedef int Id;
```

Now I am provided many objects, each of which comes with such an `Id`, and I would like to use the `Id` as index into a `std::vector` that stores these objects. It may look something like this:

```
std::vector<SomeObj*> vec(size);
std::pair<Id, SomeObj*> p = GetNext();
vec[p.first] = p.second;
```

The problem is that `std::vector` uses its own type to index its elements: `std::vector::size_type` (why isn't that templated?).

So strictly, it would be better to use `std::map<Id, SomObj*>`, but that would be less efficient, and an array is what I really need here (I know that the indices of all the objects are contiguous and start with `0`). Another problem is that the `typedef int Id` might change to `typedef long int Id` or similar in the future ... (it is part of my own code though, so I control it, but ideally I should be allowed to change the `typedef` at some points; that's what a typedef is for).

How would you deal with this? Maybe use `unordered_map<Id, SomeObj*>`, where the hash function directly uses the `Id` as hash key? Would that be less memory-efficient? (I don't completely understand how `unordered_map` allocates its space given that the range of the hash function is unknown in advance?)

Comment: You missed a backquote in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass any integral type as an index for `std::vector`. If it doesn't match `std::vector<T>::size_type` (which is typically `unsigned long`) then the value will be implicitly converted.

Comment: I am 90% certain that `vector<T>::size_type` is *not* an `unsigned long`. Instead, it will almost always be a `std::size_t` which is twice as large as a `long` on some computers.

Comment: Yes, `size_type` is probably `size_t`. However, that is typically `unsigned long`. It is on my 64-bit linux system with gcc, and on my 32-bit Windows system.

Comment: 64 bit Windows is atypical, since it's LLP64, whereas 64 bit linux is LP64.

Comment: @Steve: Good point; on 64-bit Windows, `size_t` is probably `unsigned __int64`

Answer (score 3):

> why isn't that templated?

Because standard containers are implemented to use the largest unsigned type that they reasonably can. If `size_type` is `unsigned int` in your implementation then that's for a reason, and whatever the reason is that prevented the implementers using a larger type, would still exist if you asked for something else[*]. Also, for your particular example, size types have to be unsigned, and you want to use a signed type, so that's another change that would be needed to support what you want to do.

In practice, `size_type` for a standard container is (almost?) always `size_t`. So if you asked for a larger vector, you couldn't have one, because a vector is backed by contiguous storage. The vector would be unable to allocate an array bigger than `size_t` bytes.

To use your `Id` as a vector index, you can either rely on implicit conversions, or you can explicitly convert (and, perhaps, explicitly bounds check) in order to make it absolutely clear what you are doing. You could also use asserts to ensure that `Id` is no bigger than `size_type`. Something like this, although a static assert would probably be better:

```
assert(std::numeric_limits<Id>::max() <= std::numeric_limits<std::vector<SomeObj*>::size_type>::max());
```

A `map<Id, SomeObj*>` would be a good option if the Id values in use are sparse. If the only valid Ids are 1 and 400,000,000, then a vector would be rather wasteful of memory.

If it makes you feel any more comfortable, remember that the literal `0` has type `int`, not `vector<SomeObj*>::size_type`. Most people have no qualms about writing `vec[0]`: indeed it's used in the standard.

[*] Even if that reason is just, "the implementers think that 4 billion elements is enough for anyone".

Answer (score 2):

Write your own container wrapper that takes `Id` as the index type. Use `map` or `unordered_map` internally to implement the container. Program against this wrapper. If it turns out that this implementation is too slow, switch to `vector` internally and convert you `Id` index to `vector::size_type` (also internally, of course).

This is the cleanest approach. But really, `vector::size_type` will be some very large unsigned integer type so a conversion from `Id` to `vector::size_type` will always be safe (but not the other way round!).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `Id` is an `int` (more accurately, `signed int`), can be negative. If the `Id` was an unsigned type, e.g. `typedef unsigned int Id;`, there is no problem.

If my understanding correct so far, then I don't get the idea why would someone want to use a negative number as an index to `vector` (or `array`). What am I missing?